# Section hides lower part of page

Tags: html, css

For some reason, one of the sections of my page becomes the last section of my page despite having more sections below it in the HTML document. If the section is removed the other sections are shown. Is there something in the HTMl or CSS that affected my page? I need the rest of the page to be shown because it contains important information.

The HTML:

```
<!-- ===========================================================================
                START NATURAL LANGUAGE MARKUP
   =========================================================================== -->

<section id="nlmarkup">
    <div class="inner">
         <h2>Who I am. <i class="title_line"></i> </h2>

        <p class="lead">The most important thing to me is
            <br>building products people love.</p>
        <form id="nl-form" class="nl-form">"I feel like making a
            <select>
                <option value="1" selected>app</option>
                <option value="2">website</option>
                <option value="3">mockup</option>
            </select>
            <br />that is
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="(adjective)" data-subline="For example: <em>Responsive</em> or <em>Cool</em>"
            />within
            <br />the next
            <select>
                <option value="1" selected>week</option>
                <option value="1">two weeks</option>
                <option value="2">month</option>
                <option value="3">six months</option>
                <option vlaue="4">year</option>
            </select>and
            <br>delivered to me via
            <select>
                <option value="1" selected>email</option>
                <option value="1">dribbble</option>
                <option value="2">behance</option>
            </select>."
            <div class="nl-overlay"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The CSS:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'nlicons';
    src:url('../fonts/nlicons/nlicons.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/nlicons/nlicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/nlicons/nlicons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/nlicons/nlicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/nlicons/nlicons.svg#nlicons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* general style for the form */
.nl-form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0.3em auto 0 auto;
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.nl-form ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* normalize the input elements, make them look like everything else */
.nl-form input,
.nl-form select,
.nl-form button {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.nl-form input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* custom field (drop-down, text element) styling  */
.nl-field {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.nl-field.nl-field-open {
    z-index: 10000;
}

/* the toggle is the visible part in the form */
.nl-field-toggle,
.nl-form input,
.nl-form select  {
    line-height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #b14943;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #b14943;
}

/* drop-down list / text element */
.nl-field ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #00aed7;
    left: -0.5em;
    top: 50%;
    font-size: 80%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-40%) scale(0.9);
    transform: translateY(-40%) scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.nl-field.nl-field-open ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.nl-field ul li {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.nl-dd ul li {
    padding: 0 1.5em 0 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nl-dd ul li.nl-dd-checked {
    color: #478982;
}

.no-touch .nl-dd ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.no-touch .nl-dd ul li:hover:active {
    color: #478982;
}

/* icons for some elements */
.nl-dd ul li.nl-dd-checked:before,
.nl-submit:before,
.nl-field-go:before {
    font-family: 'nlicons';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.nl-dd ul li.nl-dd-checked:before {
    content: "\e000";
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    font-size: 50%;
    line-height: 3;
}

.nl-ti-text ul {
    min-width: 8em;
}

.nl-ti-text ul li.nl-ti-input input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em 2em 0.2em 0.5em;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.nl-form .nl-field-go {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
}
.nl-field-go:before {
    content: "\e001";
    font-size: 75%;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2.5;
    display: block;
}

/* custom placeholder color */
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

input:active::-webkit-input-placeholder ,
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

input:active::-moz-placeholder,
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

input:active::-ms-input-placeholder ,
input:focus::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

/* example field below text input */
.nl-ti-text ul li.nl-ti-example {
    font-size: 40%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-top: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

.nl-ti-text ul li.nl-ti-example em {
    color: #fff
}

/* submit button */
.nl-submit-wrap {
    margin-top: 0.4em;
}

/* overlay becomes visible when a field is opened */
.nl-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}

.nl-field.nl-field-open ~ .nl-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
    .nl-form {
        font-size: 3em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
    .nl-form {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a link to your site? it would be easier to debug than going through all your CSS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An additional `</div>`  towards the bottom which has no opening `<div>`.

Comment: turns out that word was not indented when I originally posted it. I updated the OP. The problem still persists though.

Answer (score 1):

You open a `section` but you close a `div`.

Any decent IDE / Text editor could warn you about it. It's time to get one or it will become a pain.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text, what would you recommend?

Comment: Sublime Text is great, there are plugins that can check HTML syntax, just look for it on the Internet.

Comment: Wow. Using the package control is amazing. I'll definitely be using this more.